# Why am I getting invalid frame header, when the server sends a message to the client after the opening handshake?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, python-sockets

I'm trying to make a basic websocket server in python, after the opening handshake, the client sends a message, and after the server has unmasked it, it is supposed to send a message, from my browser's developer tools' network tab, I can see that the client has sent the message, and from the console of my server I can see the message which has been unmasked. The problem is, that I can't seem to send a message to the client.

In the code below, I'm trying to send a single-frame unmasked text message, as seen in the example of the [websocket protocol's documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.7), but I get an error from the browser's console, after the server has sent the message:
[image: invalid frame header]

Here's my code:

```py
import socket
import threading
import hashlib
from time import sleep
from base64 import encodebytes
bind_ip = '127.0.0.1'
bind_port = 8000

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(5)

print('Listening on {}:{}'.format(bind_ip, bind_port))

def decodeMessage(bytesArr):
  if (bytesArr[0] & 0xF == 0x1):
    unmasked = bytearray(b"\x00"*len(bytesArr))
    for i in range(6, len(bytesArr)):
      j = ((i-6) % 4)
      unmasked[i] = bytesArr[i] ^ bytesArr[2+j]
    return unmasked[6:]

def handle_client_connection(client_socket):
  request = client_socket.recv(1024)
  headers = request.split(b"\r\n")
  key = b""
  for header in headers:
    if (header.find(b"Sec-WebSocket-Key:") != -1):
      key = header[19:]
  key = encodebytes(hashlib.sha1(key + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11".encode()).digest())
  client_socket.send(b"""HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Connection: upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: %s

""" % key)
  sleep(1)
  msg = decodeMessage(client_socket.recv(1024))
  print(msg)
  client_socket.send(b"\x81\x05Hello") # sending the encapsulated message

while KeyboardInterrupt:
  client_sock, address = server.accept()
  print('Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1]))
  client_handler = threading.Thread(target = handle_client_connection, args = (client_sock,))
  client_handler.start()
```

So, what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this for learning/experimental purposes, or are you trying to implement a proper Websocket server? If it's the latter, I would recommend using something more robust like [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/), which supports websockets out of the box (see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/)).

Comment: @Felipe This is only for learning purposes, however I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the issue was with the `encodebytes` function as it puts a line feed character at the end of the base64 encoded key, this can be avoided by changing `encodebytes` to `b64encode`, which works the same way.